# JQuery Wordpress enqueue scripts not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to enable a lightbox gallery plugin on my website along with a sliding menu and fading functions.

When I load JQuery in the HTML head with  tags, the sliding menu and fading functions work fine. No Jquery Wordpress plugins are working though.

When I comment out the script tags in the HTML head and try and load JQuery from the functions.php file, JQuery will not load. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

I have tested several Wordpress plugins that require JQuery and none seem to work, no matter what way I try and load JQuery.

Comment: Why are you trying to load jQuery again? WordPress already includes WordPress. See http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: That didn't work for me. Wordpress is not loading JQuery by default either.

Comment: Open up `header.php` and check you're using `wp_head();`

Comment: Hey Nathan, I am using wp_head(); and wp_footer(); and still nothing.

Comment: Please do not put [SOLVED] or similar in the title.  Please post the solution as an answer below and accept that answer as soon as allowed.  Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is already registered in wordpress so you just need to enqueue it. Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php 
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```